# onQueryTextChanged Method in the searchView method goes backwards without filtering/publishing search results

Tags: android, search, searchview

I have a strange issue with onQueryTextChanged method with SearchView in android. My problem is that when specific text e.g: "Al a" has been entered (i.e. right after entering in letter 'a' in the search Field) the searchView closes by itself. But if I enter in "Al A" i.e. capitalizing 'a' there is no issue. Similarly the same issue persists with "Al b", "Al c",.....etc etc. At first I thought it had something to do with escape sequences but that's not true. I am clueless, please help.

```
private void search(SearchView searchView) {
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {

                System.out.println("text entered="+newText);

                if (condition!= null) {
                    if (newText.length()!=0) { //if newText is not empty
                    } else {
isFiltersActive = false;
                    }
                    ListAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                } else
                    isFiltersActive = false;
                return true;
            }
        });
        searchView.setOnCloseListener(new SearchView.OnCloseListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onClose() {
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: please post the code.

Comment: please check the message again. I have added code to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
onQueryTextSubmit:
```

> Called when the user submits the query. This could be due to a key
>   press on the keyboard or due to pressing a submit button. The listener
>   can override the standard behavior by returning true to indicate that
>   it has handled the submit request. Otherwise return false to let the
>   SearchView handle the submission by launching any associated intent.

Return true from `onQueryTextSubmit` function.
To Check whether String is empty or not, Use 
`TextUtils.isEmpty()`  Returns true if the string is null or 0-length.